# Why do I get a warning when creating a custom slash screen?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Why do I get this warning when I try to create my custom splash screen?
[image: Warning Screenshot]

Can I get rid of this without using `@SuppressLint("CustomSplashScreen")`

Comment: I guess you **have** to use that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because with android-12 there is a new API to build [Splash Screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen)  . You can go through the [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate) if you want to implement new API . If you want keep older one you have to use `@SupressLint` because you are targeting android-12.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I get this warning when I try to create my custom splash screen?

You are encouraged to migrate to the [SplashScreen API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen) that is available on Android 12, with a [backport](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#core_splashscreen_version_10_2) available in AndroidX libraries (currently alpha).

> Can I get rid of this without using @SuppressLint("CustomSplashScreen")

There are some other ways to [suppress lint warnings](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#config) such as using an XML file or configuring it with gradle. In this case I'd prefer the `@SuppressLint` annotation since it's the most local.

Or, just get rid of your custom splash screen to keep lint happy here.